# .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid System Tray Icon

Tags: .net, blazor, .net-maui, maui-blazor

I'm currently exploring .NET MAUI with Blazor which i find it really cool.
It is pretty obvious that it's a new framework and it's content and tutorials are scarse, that's why i'm here asking.

**Is there any kind of way of to make the a MAUI app display a System tray icon and handle actions via that icon?**

Example:
[Tray icon image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHgEc.png)

If theres any kind of documentation, toolkit or anyone has faced the same issue it would help me a lot!

PD:
I've seen a couple of examples which i can't seem to make them work on my project for 3rd party libraries (hardcodet) that doesnt seem to work on a blazor maui project, for example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxgooETfJug&t=0s&ab_channel=CodingFlamingo